# Why EOF is not in the buffer?

Tags: c

Make code looks like this:

```
  #include <stdio.h>

  /*Program 1*/
  int main(void) {
      int c;

      while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
          putchar(c);
      }

      return 0;
  }
```

I was trying to figure out why is that for the input:

> > aa <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> //=> aa

And for the input:

> > <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> //=> The program properly ends.

Why in the first example EOF doesn't cause the program to exit.

Comment: The question in the title is different from he question in the body.

Comment: What would you propose for the more meaningful title here? I wasn't sure how to name this question.

Comment: Well, I suggest that you make up your mind what the question is, and then write it in both places (title and body).

Comment: Thanks @Marian. Sorry for the duplicate.